# Designing a multilevel company structure

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I try to build a database model for the following structure:
I have companies with **up to** 3 hierachical levels. For each unit I have a value (these values are given randomly and duplicates between companies (not within) are possible. Let us say (1 Level: 222-Amazon, 2 Level: 441-Amazon: Germany, 542-Britan, 3 Level: 6-Distribution, 99-Shop, 124-Programming, 5-HR.
Of course for each company this is different. What I did is:

```
Table1:
ID_Worker
CompanyName
ID_CompanyLvL1
ID_CompanyLvL2
ID_CompanyLvL3
...
Table2:
ID_CompanyLevel1
Slot1
Slot2
...
Table3:
ID_CompanyLevel2
Slot1
Slot2
...
```

But with this approach I have the following problem: If two companies have the same number for a CompanyLevel1(2 or 3) unit I cannot distingush them anymore.

Another approach that is not working is

```
   Table1:
    ID_Company
    ID_Worker
    ID_CompanyLevel1
    ...
    Tabel2:
    ID_CompanyLevel1
    Slot1
    ID_CompanyLevel2
    ...
    Table3:
    ID_CompanyLevel2
    Slot
    ID_CompanyLevel3
    ...
```

With this approach I cannot identify which person is in e.g. which level2 unit. Could anyone help me with this i just cannot come up with the right design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to decide whether the organization structure is purely hierarchical (an org unit can only belong to 0 or 1 other org unit), or whether it is graphical (an org unit can belong to 0, 1, or 1+ org units).
2. Your limit of three is a business rule, and should be enforced by database logic (trigger) and not the database schema.
3. Why the codes with the names?

If hierarchical, this is your schema:

```
create table organizations (
  organization_id int primary key,
  name varchar(whatever) not null,
  parent_id int null references organizations(organization_id)
);
```

Use [Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to query them.

If graphical, this is your schema:

```
create table organizations (
  organization_id int primary key,
  name varchar(whatever) not null
);

create table organizations_structure (
  parent_organization_id int references organizations(organization_id),
  child_organization_id int references organizations(organization_id),

  primary key (parent_organization_id, child_organization_id),

  check (parent_organization_id <> child_organization_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anything like that - make sure you do not put yourself into a cornder. For example:

> I have companies with up to 3 hierachical levels

No. YOu do have companies with CURRENTLY up to 3 hierarchical levels. And they do not want to scream at you when one of them decides to have 4.

I would suggest reading the Data Model Ressource Book Volume 1 - they describe all kinds of stuff and standard data schemata, among them entity organizations (entity as in "legal, human or organizatonal entity" which includes organigrams. Things are a lot more complex as you think when you do not want to put yourself into a corner that WILL make the program require a rewrite in the not too far future.

Comment: I just ordered the book. Thanks for your answer. I will not mark it as ansered since it doesnt provide a detailed solution (just dont want to confuse other searcher with the same problem).

Comment: Well, noone will give a detailed solution - that is a "make my architecture" consulting job and out of the scope for this site.